# Prevent "Formulas have been recalculated, save" dialog?

Tags: c#, excel-interop

How can I prevent the "Formulas have been recalculated, save" dialog that is launched by Excel interop when quitting the app?

```
xlApp.Quit();
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlApp);
```

Comment: Did you try setting `DisplayAlerts` to `false`?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the Workbook.Saved property to true before attempting to close the workbook.